# x509: must the signature algorithm and public key algorithm match?

Tags: encryption, certificates, public-key-infrastructure

I'm having trouble getting Firefox to send an encrypted message using a certificate, and I've found that the only difference between this one and others that work fine are that this one has a DSA public key while the others have an RSA key. The signature algorithm still says "sha512WithRSAEncryption". I'm wondering if that is causing a problem since the public key algorithm is not RSA.

Comment: If the public key uses DSA but the signature is created using RSA (out at least claims this), how could that work?

Comment: I do not know. I got the request, imported it into XCA, signed it, exported the resulting cert in PEM format, inspected with openssl x509 and that's what it shows - a DSA key, but a signature algorithm that says RSA.

Comment: Could it be that the user certificat itself has a DSA key and the CA certificate uses a RSA key? That would be Ok.

Comment: @mkl That's probably what's happening. The CA key is definitely RSA. The openssl output isn't very clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The signature in the certificate is computed by the CA, and must match the public key *of the CA*. There is no problem with having a certificate which *contains* a DSA key while being signed by a CA which uses a RSA key.

There is a big problem, though, with trying to encrypt some data with a DSA key. DSA is only for [digital signatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature).